# Use chewy to connect a rails app to elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, chewy-gem

I am using the chewy gem to tie ES to my rails app.I am new to chewy, so i am facing a problem when i try to index a field of my model. The field is a text field in the DB which i serialize as a Hash in my model. The hash is dynamic and might have 0 to n elements in it in the form. The field name is **items** Any help would be much appreciated.

```
{"0"=>{"property"=>"value","property"=>"value"},"1"=>{"property"=>"value","property"=>"value"}.......}
```

how can I index such field in my index class when i do define_type?

This is my indexer

```
require 'typhoeus/adapters/faraday'
class ModelNameIndex < Chewy::Index
  define_type ModelName do
  field :user_id, type: 'integer'
  field :enduser_id, type: 'integer'
  field :items, type: 'object'
  field :created, type: 'date', include_in_all: false,
    value: ->{ created_at } 
  end
end
```

My model

```
class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
  update_index('IndexName#name') { self }
  belongs_to :user
  serialize :items, Hash
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above works fine

```
require 'typhoeus/adapters/faraday'
class ModelNameIndex < Chewy::Index
  define_type ModelName do
  field :user_id, type: 'integer'
  field :enduser_id, type: 'integer'
  field :items, type: 'object'
  field :created, type: 'date', include_in_all: false,
         value: ->{ created_at } 
  end
end
```

If someone gets a parsing error make sure ElasticSearch does not has a any of they keys you are defining  previously defined, or it will throw an error.

Comment: Thanks for the Question and Answer. I have similar situation, my doubt is how to search and filtering on field 'items'. for eg:- get all rows in ModelName those property values greater than "specific value" for key "1" in items Object.